# HTML/CSS Image and Color Blending

Tags: css, photoshop

Trying to "translate" photoshop design into HTML/CSS code and got stuck with color/image blending problem.

In Photoshop design I have layers as following:

- Image (20% opacity)
- Background color (100% opacity)

This translates into something like this:

[image]

Now in theory I could swap the order or the layers (image 100% opacity and background color 80%) but overall result would look different:

[image]

Here is how I have to wrap them:

```
<footer>
background image is visible here
<div>color overlay visible here</div>
</footer>
```

Exporting merge background is not an option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @AbraarArique - trying to recreate the PS mockup in actual HTML/CSS. OP - what CSS have you got?

Answer (score 3):

you could give a try to [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

```css
div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVaPl.png);
  padding-top: 5em;
}
p {
  background: #4770AC;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

gradients bg would do too

```css
div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVaPl.png);
  padding-top: 5em;
}
p {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#4770AC, tomato);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVaPl.png);
  padding-top: 5em;
}
p {
  background: #4770AC;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size:2em;
}

<div>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

`rgba()` (or `hsla()`) colors could be a fallback

```css
div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVaPl.png);
  padding-top: 5em;
}
p {
  background: rgba(0, 40, 100,0.8);
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want the overlay to be on top of the background, you need to give it a z-index.

HTML:

```
<footer>
background image is visible here
<div class="overlay">color overlay visible here</div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay{
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
 }
```